# Symfony Twig extension render view

Tags: symfony, twig, render

My twig extension code is as follows

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('bsPanelTitle', array($this, 'bsPanelTitle')),
    ];
}


/**
 * @param $headline
 * @return string
 */
public function bsPanelTitle($headline)
{
    $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/views/Common/Placeholder');
    $twig = new \Twig_Environment($loader);
    return $twig->render('xtitle.html.twig', ['headline' => $headline]);
}
```

My question is:

Is there a better way to reach AppBundle/Resources/views/Common/Placeholder folder from a Twig extension function?

Comment: You should just `include` the placeholder in your main template

Comment: The bsPanelTitle will be used all over the application. It renders css bootstrap markup along with an headline. I do not want to copy that markup in every twig file. So I want to use it as a function.

Comment: one more thing i discovered


you can put all the helper view templates in a folder instead of folder and subfolder (which I was doing)

change your function defination as follows

 /**
  * @return array
  */
 public function getFunctions()
 {
  return [
   new \Twig_SimpleFunction('bsPanelTitle', [$this, 'bsPanelTitle'],
    ['needs_environment' => true]),
  ];
 }

 public function bsPanelTitle(\Twig_Environment $environment, $headline)
 {
  return $environment->render('AppBundle:Common:xtitle.html.twig', ['headline' => $headline]);
 }

it looks much cleaner :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question is tagged with symfony2, I'm assuming you are indeed talking about symfony2 project, and if that is the case you can registering your own namespaces with twig, using the twig config, something like this:

```
twig:
    # ...
    paths:
        "%kernel.root_dir%/../pathFromProjectRootToPlaceholder/Placeholder": placeholder
```

This creates an alias to the folder pathFromProjectRootToPlaceholder/Placeholder and then you can use it to render your templates like this:

```
//from controller
return $this->render(
    '@placeholder/index.html.twig',
    $data
);
```

OR

```
{# from twig template #}
{% include '@placeholder/index.html.twig' %}
```

You can add multiple paths to the same alias, but for more information check the official cookbook on symfony 2 site:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/namespaced_paths.html

Hope this helps,

Alexandru Cosoi

Answer (score 1):

As stated in a comment, use include() to include the template wherever you will need it.

For example, the following is the same as what you're trying to achieve:

*app/Resources/views/xtitle.html.twig:*

```
{% stylesheets '@AppBundle/Resources/css/bootstrap.css' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}

{# Other Markup Here #}
```

In your templates, simply call:

```
{% include 'xtitle.html.twig' %}
```

This will include the template along with the bootstrap styles and anything else in that template.

Comment: your solution could work as well but with php code I can write tests on it

kind of view helper test